# Install InkScape without XQuartz

Tags: macos, install, xquartz

Is it possible to install InkScape without XQuartz?

I did install it already and it's working but I feel like it's not that native (e.g. the menu doesn't appear on the top pannel but until the title bar).

How to install InkScape without XQuartz?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since some time has passed, I thought it might be good to post an update:

### YES

You can now install Inkscape from a Disk Image (.dmg) file, and there is no need to run it through XQuartz. Rejoice!

The current version as of this writing is [**1.2.1** (download link)](https://inkscape.org/release/inkscape-1.2.1/mac-os-x/)

There are two installers, one for Intel Macs, and one for ARM64 Macs.

---

For anyone unsure of their processor type, check here: [image]

---

The installer has a nice little splash screen. Installation is drag-and-drop. It all feels very familiar to a Mac user, and there's no hassle at all.

[image]

The first time you launch Inkscape, there is a screen to assist with the initial settings:

[image]

And it's as simple as that to get started.

In my experience so far there have been a couple of quirks with keyboard shortcuts not being what one might expect.

Hide Inkscape (expecting <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>H</kbd>, has no shortcut assigned, and while normally [you can assign one](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/create-keyboard-shortcuts-for-apps-mchlp2271/mac), and [I did try](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qYtSH.png), it does not respond except while accessing one of Inkscape's menu items using the mouse).

Also, when the menu shows a keyboard shortcut containing `+`, what is meant is literally <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>=</kbd>, not [the Apple convention](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210978) of listing all modifier keys like Shift explicitly. This means if you see <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>+</kbd>, translate that as <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>=</kbd>.

But these are small issues, and the current Inkscape offers considerable improvements over previous versions, beginning with a nice new polished interface.

Answer (score 17):

Not officially possible, yet—the Inkscape developers will have to remove the XQuartz dependency by switching to the native Gtk and Glib libraries for OS X, just like the [GIMP team did a few years ago](http://lifehacker.com/5938890/gimp-is-now-available-as-a-native-app-for-mac-os-x).

This work has been in progress for a couple of years on a [separate Inkscape branch](https://code.launchpad.net/~suv-lp/inkscape/osxmenu), but there is no official release yet. However, you can download the latest DMG [here](https://inkscape.org/en/~su_v/galleries/osxmenu-r12922/) (currently based on Inkscape 0.91) both for GTK2 and GTK3 (experimental), at your own risk—expect bugs and crashes.

Comment: Hmm, I tried that build and it doesn't work at all. But yeah, I understand the issue. Thanks!

Comment: I tried it too, and it worked okay (MBP, 10.10.5)... took a very long time to load the first time, though.

Comment: Both GTK2 and GTK3 builds worked fine on MBP 10.13.3. They take a while to start the first time, but I assume that's due to the same fc-cache run that holds up a fresh start of the XQuartz version.

Answer (score 6):

Inkscape 1.0 will include first class support for Mac OS X with no need for XQuartz.

If you are willing to try alpha software, you can download a dmg right now from https://inkscape.org/release/inkscape-1.0/?latest=1 by clicking on the Mac OS X and then choose Apple's Mac OS X Desktop.

Or click, A build from the CI build Alpha Tarball to build from the command line.